# How to install docker and docker-compose on Ubutntu 22.04?

Tags: apt, docker

I do everything like said in the guide but I get
The guide that I used: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/

```
user@pc:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package docker-ce is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package docker-ce-cli is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'docker-ce-cli' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package containerd.io
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'containerd.io'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'containerd.io'
E: Unable to locate package docker-compose-plugin
```

When I try installing dependencies I get these errors

```
user@pc:~/Downloads$  sudo apt install lsb-release ca-certificates apt-transport-https software-properties-common -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
ca-certificates is already the newest version (20211016).
lsb-release is already the newest version (11.1.0ubuntu4).
software-properties-common is already the newest version (0.99.22.3).
software-properties-common set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 docker-desktop : Depends: qemu-system-x86 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: docker-ce-cli but it is not installable
                  Depends: pass but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: uidmap
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I install docker I get this:

```
user@pc:~/Downloads$ echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null


user@pc:~/Downloads$  sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
Get:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease [48,9 kB]       
Get:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1 811 B]         
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]      
Ign:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rock-core/qt4/ubuntu jammy InRelease    
Hit:8 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                              
Get:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy/stable amd64 Packages [6 255 B]
Err:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4EB27DB2A3B88B8B
Err:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rock-core/qt4/ubuntu jammy Release     
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Ign:11 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                         
Get:12 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco Release [6 598 B]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [11,4 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [10,1 kB]
Get:15 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco Release.gpg [473 B]    
Get:16 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages [1 169 B]
Get:17 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco/main i386 Packages [1 163 B]
Reading package lists... Done             
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4EB27DB2A3B88B8B
E: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rock-core/qt4/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: https://repo.skype.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/disco/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.


user@pc:~/Downloads$  sudo apt install docker-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 docker-ce : Depends: containerd.io (>= 1.4.1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: docker-ce-cli but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: docker-ce-rootless-extras but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: pigz but it is not going to be installed
 docker-desktop : Depends: qemu-system-x86 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: docker-ce-cli but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: pass but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: uidmap
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

What do I do please help!

Comment: I ended up using apt-get to install docker from default repos, the guide at the official website and other websites is trash

Comment: @kaerl I know how to use apt and PPA. It doesn't fix my issue. My issue is that every Ubuntu version works differently than the previous one and the whole Linux ecosystem doesn't have any reliability. So guides get outadet quickly, but the search results doesn't reflect this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/q/140246/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 8):

this problem is answered by docker it self check this [page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/linux/#install-the-plugin-manually)
you can Install the plugin manually

To download and install the Compose CLI plugin, run:

```
 DOCKER_CONFIG=${DOCKER_CONFIG:-$HOME/.docker}
 mkdir -p $DOCKER_CONFIG/cli-plugins
 curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.12.2/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o $DOCKER_CONFIG/cli-plugins/docker-compose
```

This command downloads the latest release of Docker Compose (from the Compose releases repository) and installs Compose for the active user under `$HOME` directory.

To install:

Docker Compose for all users on your system, replace `~/.docker/cli-plugins` with `/usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins`.
A different version of Compose, substitute v2.12.2 with the version of Compose you want to use.
Apply executable permissions to the binary:

```
 chmod +x $DOCKER_CONFIG/cli-plugins/docker-compose
```

or, if you chose to install Compose for all users:

```
 sudo chmod +x /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
```

Test the installation.

```
 docker compose version
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
sudo pip3 install docker-compose
```

It helps in my case